# Using :nth-child in a node js for loop throws Syntax Error

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to crawl a site that has multiple similar elements and store them in a json object so I can then insert them into my database. Crawling works fine but when I try to make a loop to store each element's content, my only good solution so far resulted in a Syntax Error: n-th rule couldn't be parsed ('i')

This is the code

```
for(var i = 1; i <= childElementter; i++) {
            json.name = $("#list_new").find("li:nth-child(i)").find("h3").children().text();
            json.latinname = $("#list_new").find("li:nth-child(i)").find("h4").children().text();
            json.family = $("#list_new").find("li:nth-child(i)").find("p").children().text();
            nodeList[i] = json;
       }
```

Using cheerio

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with markup:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= childElementter; i++) {
            json.name = $("#list_new").find("li:nth-child(" + i + ")").find("h3").children().text();
            json.latinname = $("#list_new").find("li:nth-child( " + i + " )").find("h4").children().text();
            json.family = $("#list_new").find("li:nth-child( " + i +" )").find("p").children().text();
            nodeList[i] = json;
        }
```